# DC supply voltage in op amps and instrumentation amplifiers

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

My question is very simple, i dont have much experience with electronics, and i am developing a project where i will use some operational amplifiers (TL081) and 1 instrumentation amplifier (INA118).

I'll need the TL081 to build voltage followers, and a Voltage-Controlled Current Source (Mirrored Modified Howland):

[image]

*Source: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/407/1/012030/pdf*

The INA118 amplifies the input voltage from the two electrodes placed on the body. [Similar to this project.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Body-Composition-using-BIA/?ALLSTEPS)

In these cases, do I need to use a DC supply voltage in my ICs TL081 and INA118?
I was looking at projects that use applications similar to mine, and I did not see any comments about it.

Thanks!

Comment: The opamp and the instrumentation amp will both need a DC powersupply.  Use batteries since you are attaching this to a human body.  Amplifiers ALL need a powersupply to operate.  Given your lack of basic knowledge, please reconsider carrying out your project - you may hurt yourself or someone else when connecting to people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to provide power supplies to any op-amp or in-amp in your circuit if you want them to act like op-amps and in-amps.

You can see in the datasheet (INA118 shown) this is specified in the "recommended operating conditions" table:
[image]

Most of the other specifications in the datasheet are only valid if you are operating the chip according to the recommended operating conditions.